# error: expected expression before

Tags: c, struct

```
struct student{
char name[100];
int id;
char *department;
struct result{
  float gpa;
  char grade;
 };
}W[1],R[1];
W[] = {{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",3.05,'A'},
      {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",3.5,"A+"}};
```

When I am compiling it, compiler gives an error, the error is,

```
error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
W[] = {
```

what is the problem? I think I am right but why is it giving the error?

Comment: Is `W` supposed to contain one entry or two?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that arrays cannot be assigned like that.

Try splitting the type definition from the declaration of variables.

```
struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int id;
    char *department;
    struct the_result
    {
        float gpa;
        char grade;
    } result;
};
```

and then define `W` as;

```
struct student W[] = 
   {
       {"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics", {3.05,'A'}},
       {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil", {3.5, 'A'}}
   };
```

Note that I have changed string literal to from `"A+"` to a `char` literal in the second, since a single `char` cannot represent a string (which consists of multiple characters).

Note also the pair of additional `{}` for initialising the nested `struct`.

If you want to represent grades as strings, change `grade` into be an array of `char`, not a single `char`.

It is probably advisable to change the `department` member to also be an array.   A pointer is something different.

Lastly, keep in mind that a string literal like `"AB"` is represented as an array of `char` with an additional `char` of value `'\0'`.   So `"AB"` is represented as an array of three `char` with values `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'\0'`.

If you don't understand the changes I've suggested, you need to read a basic text more closely to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
struct student{
    char name[100];
    int id;
    char *department;
    struct result{
        float gpa;
        char grade;
    } resultStruct;
} W[2] =
{{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",3.05,'A'},
      {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",3.5,'A'}};
```

you must have a var in a nest struct.

Comment: what is the problem if i decare W[2] some where else in the code or declare it with some input from stdin??

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared `W` haven't you , and then you try to assign to an array . This is the problem .

Do declaration and initialisation of `W` at same time. Something like this-

```
struct student A[]={{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",{3.05,'A'}},
                {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",{3.5,'B'}}};
```

Also you could write your struct declarations more clearly -

```
struct result{
   float gpa;
   char grade[3];
};
struct student{
   char name[100];
   int id;
   char *department;
   struct result x;
}W[1],R[1];
```

Comment: Why do i do declaration and initialization at the same time? If I want W[ ]

Comment: W[ ] to be used somewhere else then what would i do in that case?

Comment: if i want to decalre and initialize an array of type struct, then what is the problem

Comment: @SaudFarooqui I clearly don't understand your point .  What do you mean by `W[]` ? And of you last point , what I said the same  thing . To store struct's data you need to declare array of struct.

Comment: *of type struct separately

Comment: @SaudFarooqui  ok , yes you can do that . I show that in declaration of `A` in my answer. You can do that in `main` and use the . That is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this context W is an array and you must always use an index to initialize 
If there are 5 elements int a[5]
a[]={1};
In this context the same error is produced .....

if you want to initialise

int a[]={1,2,3,4};

Should do like this and not 
int a[5];
a[]={1,2,3,4,5}

```
W[1],R[1];
W[] = {{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",3.05,'A'},
  {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",3.5,"A+"}};
```

You are creating 1 variable and initializing 2 values ?

And always remember the usage of nested structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char *name;
    struct marks
    {
        int eng;
        int marks;
    }m;
}v={"StackOverFlow",35,56};
void main()
{
    printf("%s\n",v.name);
    printf("%d\n",v.m.eng);
    printf("%d\n",v.m.marks);

}
```

Always create a variable to use nested structure(i.e m in above example)

Answer (score 0):

where the code contains `W[]` the compiler has no idea what to do.

Initialization must be done when the variable is created. (and the variable `W[1]` will only contain 1 instance of data, not 2 instances.

In general, best to keep the struct definition separate from any instances of that struct.

So, first define the struct:

```
struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int id;
    char *department;
    struct result
    {
        float gpa;
        char grade;
    };
};
```

then declare any instances of the struct:

```
struct student R[1];
struct student W[] = 
{
    {"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",3.05,'A'},
    {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",3.5,"A+"}
};
```

BTW: it is usually best to not try and crowd everything into a single line of code

for clarity, I recommend including the inner set of braces for the embedded struct, as in:

```
struct student W[] = 
{
    {"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",{3.05,'A'}},
    {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",{3.5,"A+"}}
};
```

However, there is one more problem, with the data

This field `char grade;`  is being declared as a single char; but, the data for 'Talha' is showing an array of char `"A+"`

TO handle that array of char,  first the struct definition needs to be changed to:

```
struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int id;
    char *department;
    struct result
    {
        float gpa;
        char grade[3];
    };
};
```

and then modify the data to always have any array for the 'grade' field:

```
struct student W[] = 
{
    {"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",{3.05,"A"}},
    {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",{3.5,"A+"}}
};
```

Notice the data for the 'grade' field is now always an array.